# Is disk space wasted when an ISO is mounted?

Tags: mount

When we do `mount -o loop filename.iso /path/to/mountdir`, is twice the memory required to store the files? If no resources are used, can I mount hundreds of ISOs at a time? As in, is it like a softlink to original files or a copy of files in ISO?

Comment: Do you mean memory, or disk space? They are two different concepts, and you seem to be confusing the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a mount point and it means that it is a **window** to see your files. The mount point is a connection point which connect the system to a resource..so it doesn't consume any resources, but the directory that you connect to the mount point will become **unused** for the system until it holds the mounted device, even if it has data inside.

Comment: _Some_ (kernel internal) resources are consumed, so you can't do this with thousands of images with impunity.

Comment: as a test in SLES 11.4 i did `mount -o loop` on five separate iso files for a total of 18GB mounted.  While using `top` and `free -m` I saw little change.  However at some point because of disk caching if you were to read every file out of an iso container then I suspect that would then take up as much RAM as the iso container takes up on disk.  But simply mounting and perusing the folders doesn't seem to consume much RAM.