# Mounted partition taking up space in root directory

Tags: mount, disk-usage

On my laptop I have a `Data` partition which I use to store all my data across multiple linux installations and a seperate `"OS"`-partition where my OS is installed on.

I have the `Data` partition mounted to `/Data/` and this mounting is done via an entry in `/etc/fstab`.

It now seems that the size of `Data` is taking up space in my root directory as that one is now completey full with absolutely no space left. I verified that the `Data`-size is being seen as part of the total used spacec on my root partition by checking the folder's size inside my root directory using `du`. That showed that `Data` seems to be taking up space in my root directory.

Why is that so? I always thought mounting a device is like providing a link to the respective drive so that I can access my data via `/Data/` while they still are on their separate drive ([This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/is-disk-space-wasted-when-an-iso-is-mounted) seems to back this idea up).

EDIT: output of `df -h / /Data`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        32G   30G  1.2G  97% /
/dev/sda5        92G   17G   71G  19% /Data
```

Comment: can you run a `lsblk` and confirm that the drive is actually mounted where you think it's supposed to be? Your understanding of how mounting works is correct.

Comment: check the "mount" command as well for checking if you have a correct mount. You can verify if your fstab is correct by unmounting /Data/ and fireing "mount -a" on a terminal. If the mount is clear, everything should be fine.

Comment: Furthermore, you can use 'sudo du -sh /*' to identify which directory is using the space.

Comment: Also  "du -x /" will only take into account the data that is really on the root filesystem, not on any mounted filesystems.

Comment: please add output of `df -h / /Data` to your question.   Also, is there any possibility that the `/Data` partition was not mounted at some point and you copied files to it? At that point, /Data would not be a separate partition, it would just be a sub-directory of the root fs, so if that happened, and `/Data`'s partition was later mounted, the mounted fs would hide all the files in the `/Data` sub-directory.

Comment: I used `lsblk` and `mount` in order to make sure that the respective partition (`/dev/sda5/`) is indeed mounted to `/Data/` and I checked the disk space using `sudo du -sxh /` but it stilled showed me the `/Data/` folder with the respective 17G of disk usage. However according to Gerad H. Pille this shouldn't have been the case if it were only mounted...

Comment: @cas I added the requested information. It's not impossible that I did access `/Data` while it was not yet mounted. However that shouldn't have been in a way that would fill up my root directory... I tried to unmount `/Data` but it didn't work because it said the drive was busy. Will try to reboot without mounting it in the first place in order to check what happens then.

Comment: Okay I now have `Data` unmounted and the problem still persists. However there was an entry I have overseeen before: My `/var` dir is several gigbytes big because of `/var/log/kern.log` which alone takes 8G. Will investigate further but I think that the problem doesn't actually has something to do with the mounted drive. Thanks though for your help!

Comment: that doesn't surprise me.  I was about to suggest looking in `/var/log`.  partly because it's not uncommon for log files to fill up `/`, partly because you haven't given any really compelling evidence that the problem is `/Data` (e.g. `du /` won't exclude other filesystems unless you tell it to with `-x`.  And if you run something like `du -shx /*`, it will still include /Data because you explicitly listed it on the command line).

Comment: BTW, you've got plenty of space on /Data, so you might be better off moving `/var/log` to, e.g., `/Data/log` and then symlinking from `/Data/log/` to `/var/log`.  This can only be done while there are no processes with open files in `/var/log`.  e.g. do it from a rescue disk or initrd shell with the filesystems mounted.  or while syslogd and/or journald and other things that write to /var/log are not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already stated in the comments: I have overseen that the thing that actually took up all the space was `/var/log` which coincidentally had the same size as my `Data` partition which caused the confusion on my side.

Therefore the whole thing did not have anything to do with `Data` being mounted.